# vscode-chrome-debug Failed to load resource ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: visual-studio-code

Installed the vscode-chrome-debug extention and attempted to launch an angular.js site.  I'm able to connect to the chrome debugger, but accessing any resources via localhost:9009 like /index.html or /json fail to load.  Running chrome with developer mode on to disable extensions.

Has anyone dealt with this before?  Is this a bug in the extension?  If anyone sees anything I'm doing wrong please let me know.  Thanks!

[image]

**launch.json**

```
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:9009/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "diagnosticLogging": true,
            "userDataDir": "c:\\out\\chrome\\",
            "sourceMaps": false
        }
```

**debug console output**

```
      ›OS: win32 ia32
      ›Node: v5.10.0
      ›vscode-chrome-debug-core: 0.1.7
      ›debugger-for-chrome: 0.4.6
      ›spawn('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', ["--remote-debugging-port=9222","--no-first-run","--no-default-browser-check","--user-data-dir=c:\\out\\chrome\\","http://localhost:9009/index.html"])
      ›Attempting to attach on 127.0.0.1:9222
    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://localhost:9009/index.html)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a missing step in my setup...  I need to run a web server!  Seems obvious but I was under the assumption that the debug extension was doing something under the covers to serve up the site given the static file location.

I setup a gulpfile and task to run a gulp-webserver.  I ran the launch task and then launched the debugger and it worked.

Comment: What a simple fix, you'd have thought this would be in the contributions section of the Debugger for Chrome.  Thank you!  I'm up and running now...

Comment: I think it's understood by developers that work with tools like Grunt, Gulp and Node more than myself (at the time).  Now that I've been swimming in the front end stack more it makes complete sense.